# Cannot find deleted document in recycle bin

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, item

I have a document library. Someone had deleted a document 3 days ago. Then user needs to restore back to the same location right now.

But this document does exist in Recycle Bin, I check the **Admin Recycle Bin**, I did not find it. How can I **restore this document** and find **who** had deleted it ?

I had tried :

```
$web = Get-SPWeb https://xxxxxx
$web.RecycleBin | ?{$_.Title -match "Document Title"}
```

It does not work, Powershell does not display information about the document

Thank you all

---

Hi, I found the solution.
In fact, user did not **archive the document**......

I am administor, but I cannot see it. I should go to Library Settings--> Manage file without archived version.

But I don't undersand. Before I check this option, I use these scripts, and PowerShell returns "items does not exist in the list, maybe deleted by another user". The truth is that document in the library, but it does not archive. Really weird.....

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://xxxxxx
$list = $web.Lists["Documents Library"]
$list.GetItemById(201)
```

Comment: Check your audit logs to confirm the delete details.

Comment: Is there any retention policy written for that particular document library. If so then the document might have been moved to another location.

Comment: @Bunzab, it cannot be found in audit logs, so strange.......

Comment: @NiranjanKulkarni, maybe, I am not sure, I search by document name, but I did not find it. And I try to upload a document to this library. All work well

Comment: You can go to, Library Settings-->Information Policy Settings and check whether any policy is applied for the library item. And also can disable the policy by unchecking the enable retention checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

The possible reasons for that:

- You didn't look at the correct site, Recycle Bin in SharePoint is site-specific, a document deleted from `http://myportal/mainsites/site1` will not appear in the top-level site’s `http://myportal/mainsite/` Recycle Bin.
- Recycle Bin is not only site-specific, it is also specific for each user. Thus the Recycle Bin contents you see is limited to documents, items, lists and libraries that you’ve deleted, content deleted by other users does not show up here as I think.
- Recycle Bin does not keep deleted items forever. The default setting in SharePoint is to keep content in Recycle Bin for 30 days.

You should also make sure that the recycle bin setting has been set correctly by following:

> Open Central Administration > Application Management > Manage web application > Select your web application > from the above ribbon select > general settings > check the setting of recycle bin status > make sure it's `On`.

Also, check others settings beside Recycle Bin.

[image]

**Note:** Once the document is deleted it moved to **1st stage recycle bin**. It stays there based on the setting that I mentioned above (for 30 days). after this period finished (30 days) it moved to **2nd stage recycle bin** it also called `Site Collection Recycle Bin`.The items in the Site Collection Recycle Bin is limited to 50% of your site's quota.

**Note:** In 2nd stage recycle bin, the document can be restored only by Site Collection Administrator.